# How change the database user on the controller in Codeigniter4?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm migrating from codeignter 3 to codeigniter 4 and I'm having a hard time changing the database settings.

For example: I want the controller "Admin" to access with a configuration / database user and the controller "Site" to access with another.

I use this as a security issue, I want the "Site" controller to have access only with the query user ...

In codeigniter 3 I simply added the code at the beginning of the control to change the database as in the example below

```
$ this-> db = $ this-> load-> database ('admin', TRUE);
```

In codeigniter 4 how can I do this?

I don't want to change the database, I want to change the database user. And choose which user to use on the controller, not the model. For, when I use the admin controller I would like to use the user with access to "insert, delet, selec". When using the website controller, I would like to use the user who only has access to "select".

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I may get you right this is what you are looking for

```php
$db = \Config\Database::connect('admin', true);
```

you can have a better reference from the document [Click Here to Read More](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/connecting.html?highlight=database)